# Fill RegExp Mask in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have 100 RegEx masks like:

```
Service - (?<status>Start|End) (?<etl>\w*) - (?<date>[0-9-]{10})(?: - (?<outcome>.*))?
```

to search for something, when a RegEx finds something I extract the data to compose another (closing) sentence to search for

```
Service - End Foo - 2024-03-09
```

When searching for the closure I cannot use RegEx because it could find me another opening with different data.

So I need in java to compose a sentence by replacing the data I retrieved inside the RegEx mask. There is a way in java?

Thank You

Example (I don't implement here all method):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> rowsData = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> masks = new ArrayList<>();

        loadData(rowsData);
        loadMasks(masks);

        for (var data : rowsData) {
            String mask = findMask(data, masks);

            if (masks != null) {
                Map<String, String> values = getValues(data, mask);

                var endSentence = prepareOutcome(mask, values);

                for (var endData : rowsData) {
                    if (endData.contains(endSentence)) {
                        System.out.println("End found at " + rowsData.indexOf(endData));
                        return;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("End not found");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Finish Searching");
    }

    private static String prepareOutcome(String mask, Map<String, String> values) {
        // TODO: What can I do?

        var stringToSearch = "Service - End Foo - 2024-03-09";
        return stringToSearch;
    }

    private static void loadMasks(List<String> masks) {
        masks.add("Service - (?<status>Start|End) (?<etl>\\w*) - (?<date>[0-9-]{10})(?: - (?<outcome>.*))?");
        //... other Masks
    }

    private static void loadData(List<String> rowsData) {
        //... Other Data
        rowsData.add("Service - Start Foo - 2024-03-09");
        rowsData.add("Service - Start Foo - 2024-03-10");
        rowsData.add("Service2 - Foo something Bar - Start");
        // Other Data
        rowsData.add("Service - End Foo - 2024-03-10 - Outcome KO");
        rowsData.add("Service2 - Foo something Bar - End");
        rowsData.add("Service - End Foo - 2024-03-09 - Outcome OK");
    }

    private static String findMask(String data, List<String> masks) {
        return "Service - (?<status>Start|End) (?<etl>\\w*) - (?<date>[0-9-]{10})(?: - (?<outcome>.*))?";
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getValues(String data, String mask) {
        Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("status", "Start");
        values.put("etl", "Foo");
        values.put("date", "2024-03-09");

        return values;
    }
```

Comment: example please...input data -> what you want to do with it -> output data

Comment: What you posted [looks to be working fine](https://regex101.com/r/dDPEDI/1), what is NOT working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, i think i get it: you want to match a "Start" row of data with its corresponding "End" row of data and then print out where that end row is...is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the sample code.

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Service - Start ETL_Process1 - 2024-03-09 - Success\n" +
            "Service - End ETL_Process2 - 2024-03-10 - Failure\n" +
            "Service - Start ETL_Process3 - 2024-03-11\n" +
            "Service - End ETL_Process4 - 2024-03-12 - Timeout\n" +
            "Service - Start ETL_Process5 - 2024-03-13\n" +
            "Service - End ETL_Process6 - 2024-03-14 - Success\n";
        String regex = "Service - (?<status>Start|End) (?<etl>\\w*) - (?<date>[0-9-]{10})(?: - (?<outcome>.*))?";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);


        while (matcher.find()) {
            String status = matcher.group("status");
            String etl = matcher.group("etl");
            String date = matcher.group("date");
            String outcome = matcher.group("outcome");

            String closingSentence = "Service - " + status + " " + etl + " - " + date;
            if (outcome != null) {
                closingSentence += " - " + outcome;
            }

            System.out.println(closingSentence);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't do it becase every mask is different change position and fields